# sql server 2008 express installation fail

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

The installation fail when you try to install sql server 2008 express on an x86-based computer.Сontent error:

```
The following error has occurred:
Cannot find service{0}
Parameter name:Sqlwriter
```

Comment: This may be happening because of corrupt sql server installation , where did you download the setup from? try downloading this and install again.. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26729

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error message and post it..?